# The Upload Document button in Document Center doesn't work - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document, file-upload, document-center

In my sharepoint 2013 Document center I have the upload document button but the web part doesn't have any function to it and documents cannot be added by clicking to it, there are no option to edit the web part as well as it is a content editor.

Am I missing something here, I'm sure this button is supposed to function, how can make the button work.
[image]

As you can see from the image there is no option to enter a query here. As this button can be seen from an out of the box document center, is it there just for the appearence sake, im sure that if its there, its supposed to function as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit "Upload a Document" Web Part
2. Click near the button then click "Edit Source" in a ribbon
3. Edit the second line - Paste name of your library instead of "Documents"

[image]

[image]